# RoR - undefined method `draft?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Actually I am trying to use enum attribute in my rails 5 blog app.The problem is that when I try to toggle the status from draft to published or vice versa, I get the error stating "NoMethodError in BlogsController#toggle_status"

blogs_controller.rb

```
class BlogsController < InheritedResources::Base

  def toggle_status
    if @blog.draft?
       @blog.published!
    elsif @blog.published?
       @blog.draft!
    end

    redirect_to blogs_url, notice: "Blog status has been updated"
  end

  private

    def blog_params
      params.require(:blog).permit(:title, :body)
    end
end
```

index.html.slim

```
h1 Listing blogs

table
  thead
    tr
      th Title
      th Body
      th
      th
      th
      th

  tbody
    - @blogs.each do |blog|
      tr
        td = blog.title
        td = blog.body
        td = link_to blog.status,toggle_status_blog_path(blog)
        td = link_to 'Show', blog
        td = link_to 'Edit', edit_blog_path(blog)
        td = link_to 'Destroy', blog, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, method: :delete

br

= link_to 'New Blog', new_blog_path
```

blog.rb

```
class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: { draft: 0, published: 1 }
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :blogs do 
    member do
      get :toggle_status
    end
  end
end
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "blogs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "status", default: 0
  end
```

I don't know where I may be going wrong, I tried at my best but unable to figure it out.

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set your `@blog` instance variable.

```
def toggle_status
  @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
  ...
```